# Create data validation list for names without duplicates based on an ID

Tags: excel, excel-formula

i need to be able to create a dropdown list populated with names. the names should only show for the ID selected.

[image]

I have a cell that the care home ID is and the following formula. The problem is, is that the formula only shows one name

```
{=IF(OFFSET(Table15[Care Home],,)=C2,Table15[Resident Name],"")}
```

What i am hoping is that another dropdown list shows the each name based on the ID without duplicates

Comment: Your question is not clear to me, but do a search for `dependent dropdown` for hints on how to create one dropdown list dependent on the contents of another.  You'll have to separately create deduplicated lists. How best to do that depends on your excel version.

Answer (score 0):

OK, if i understand your question right you first want a list without duplicates based on "Care Home"-ID which can be achieved with:

> ***Note*** It's an array-formula which needs to be confirmed through <kbd>CTRL</kbd><kbd>SHIFT</kbd><kbd>ENTER</kbd>

```
 =IFERROR(INDEX($B$2:$B$100,MATCH(1,(COUNTIF(C$1:C1,B$2:B$7)=0)*(B$2:B$7<>"")*(A$2:A$7=$A$1),0)),"")
```

This formula has to be entered in second row. For the data-validation-list you have to define a name in the name-manager and apply this formula.

```
=OFFSET(Tabelle1!$C$2,0,0,SUMPRODUCT((Tabelle1!$C$2:$C$8<>"")*1),1)
```

Use that name for data-validation -> list -> `=name`. Depending on the entry in `A1` the validation list in `B2` gets filled without empty elements.

[image]

You can adapt the ranges to your needs, for example put the filtered list onto another sheet or expand the ranges.

The formula for a filtered "Care Home"-list would look like

> ***Note*** It's an array-formula which needs to be confirmed through <kbd>CTRL</kbd><kbd>SHIFT</kbd><kbd>ENTER</kbd>

```
 =IFERROR(INDEX($A$2:$A$100,MATCH(1,(COUNTIF(C$1:C1,B$A:A$7)=0)*(B$2:B$7<>""),0)),"")
```

I would leave the task of adapting the ranges to you as an excercise.